# Area Of Triangle . Given two equation and point.

Tags: linear-algebra

What does the equation $ x^2 -y^2 =0$ represent ? If the line $y-2=0 $ intersects $x^2-y^2=0$ at points A and B and if O be the origin , then find the area of OAB.

i don't understand the question .. How can a line intersect another line at two points ?    Does $x^2 + y^2 = 0 $ represent that the line is x and y intercept ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that:
\begin{align*}
x^2 - y^2 &= 0 \\
y^2 &= x^2 \\
\sqrt{y^2} &= \sqrt{x^2} \\
|y| &= |x| \\
y &= \pm x
\end{align*}
So this equation in fact represents two perpendicular diagonal lines going through the origin: one with slope $1$ and the other with slope $-1$.

Comment: can you show me some figure or a plotted graph?

Comment: Sure, just use Wolfram|Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+-+y%5E2+%3D+0%2C+y+-+2+%3D+0

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding your question lies in realizing that the equation $x^2-y^2 = 0$ does not represent a single line but 2 lines!

Lets really think about what $x^2-y^2 = 0$ is stating. It states that 2 squares (not necessarily the square of the same or of 2 different numbers) yield a difference of 0. So the squares must be equal, hence:

$x^2 = y^2$

Now we could take the root of both sides to get:

$x = y$

or

$-x = -y$

(they are the clearly the same function)

Or we could get:

$-x = y$

or

$x = -y$

(again these two equations represent the same function).

But how could one equation represent 2 functions? The key lies in the fact that squaring "gobbles" up information regarding the parity (whether a number is negative or positive) of a variable (x or y) and the result is that two different distinct equations, if squared, can end up being the same equation.

So now we know that $x^2-y^2 = 0$ represents two function. We can map them on the cartesian plane:

[image]

Now its clear that the two functions intersect at $(0,0)$, so if we are to have a triangle, then that will be a vertex (you yourself called it O).

You can algebraically check the two equations to see that indeed the point $(0,0)$ represents a solution for both.

Now you yourself showed us another line: $y-2=0$. Its up to you to show where this line intersects with the other 2 lines so that you end up having 3 points (which means you can make a triangle out of it).

Then you should be able to also find out the area of the triangle, given that the area's formula is $b*h*0.5$ (where b is the base length and h is the height).

Comment: So i have 3 equations and the lines of the equation $x^2-y^2=0$ both intersect another line at A and B. and those two equation also intersect at the origin ?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: I still can't solve it

Comment: intersections: (0,0), (-2,2) and (2,2), so A = 4*2*0.5 = 4 units.

Comment: Honestly, I fear that you have not tried hard enough as the answer very readily follows from the hints you have been given. Give it another try :) really think what it means to have squares.